# How far to run at the beginning?

Tags: running, weight-loss, training, running-training-plan

I would like to start running because someone told me that I can minimize my belly by running.

I am not very trained so I am asking how far I should start running in the beginning.

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 3):

I usually advise people to **start by aiming for time, not distance**.

- Shoot for 30 minutes, every other day. Run as much as you can, walk the rest, and try to run again.
- Don't push it too hard in the beginning: you'll likely be very sore which can make you miss workouts. You're filling up a bathtub one spoonful at a time, you can't rush the process.
- After a few weeks if you think you can run two days in a row, give it a shot.
- Once you can comfortably run for 20-30 minutes without stopping, you should evaluate what your running goals are and possibly pursue a more structured program.

Also, **if you're looking for fat loss**, consider [reading this question and answer which discusses strength training vs aerobic training](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117) in that regard.