# How do I lose body fat without losing body weight?

Tags: body-fat

Right now, I'm currently doing light exercises every other day, and I am following the [Paleo Diet](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2010/10/04/the-beginners-guide-to-the-paleo-diet/).

By light exercises, I mean :

- 10 pushups
- 15 squats
- 15 arm lifts
- Repeat for 3 sets

In the months that I have practiced this, I have seen the overall difference. However, right now, I think I've plateaued.

**What should I do to maintain my overall weight, while losing body fat?**

I believe my current weight (around 67kg?) is optimal already for my height (5'10"), so I'm pushing to maintain it while reducing my body fat.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't sweat your body weight. You'll find most muscular people will end up on the "obese" side of a basic BMI chart. Muscle weighs a lot more than fat:

[image]

I'd make these adjustments:

- Flip to [a solid program](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs), away from a routine. [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) gets a lot of love and is considered by many to be the most effective strength training program when it comes to gains in a given amount of time.
- Your body fat is primarily controlled by your diet. Reducing calories is by far the most effective way to reduce body fat.
- [Strength training, especially following a progressive loading program, will increase your metabolism by ~10%, which increases your caloric burn 24/7](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117).

That would break your plateau, address your body fat, and put you on a solid path to strength and fitness.