# Goal...in 10 months

Tags: abdominals, endurance

19 yr old female 5'8" 137 lbs. 22% +/-3% BF (caliper test), mesomorph, pear shape

Want to get to about 130 and have reasonably taut abdominal muscles. Getting ready for a friend's wedding, and I have to deliver a dance performance (the outfit exposes the midriff and more).

I've always had loose areas, but my upper body is definitely better than my lower body. I strive to eat as clean as I can and apparently am very paranoid and strict about what I eat according to others. But I don't get to working out as much as I intend to (I go once a week..also eat 5-6 small meals a day).

I know I can't spot-reduce but for ONCE in my life, I want to have a stomach that looks decently flat, and one that doesn't have noticeable rolls when I sit down.

I guess I'm like this now: http://myhealthtips.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/7-Day-Flat-Belly-Diet-Plan.jpg

This is my goal: http://www.womenfitness.net/img2012/articleimages/aug/Trim-Torsos.jpg

Do you recommend more cardio or more strength training? I always thought I should do more S.T. since I don't have too much weight to lose and I've heard ST increases EPOC. Also I thought to do heavier weight, reps til exhaustion, but a trainer told me women should do lower weight, more reps...?

Advice is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: related http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss

Comment: @EricKaufman Thanks! That kind of confirmed my ideas. I have to be consistent to see results. I can't just do it for a few months and then stop like I have earlier...

Answer (score 3):

You should have no problem doing that in 10 months.  I don't agree that [her physique is a heavy-lifter's physique](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19447/5071).  Women who lift heavy are generally much more curvy (bigger butt, trunk).  I would say that she probably runs and does high intensity interval training (HIIT) type exercises -- and that's what I'd recommend.

Take a 20-30 minute run every day and follow it up with a session of HIIT.  Exercises from [this list](http://reebokcrossfitone.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Travel-WODs.pdf) are a good place to start (obviously omitting ones that are too difficult, or include running).  Pick one to do for every day of the week, time it, then try to beat your time next week. If it only takes you 8 minutes to do a workout, do it twice: target 15-20 minutes of HIIT. You'll get in seriously good shape, and the fat will melt right off.

That said, [adaptive thermogenesis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3673773/) will be your biggest opponent. It's what makes losing weight so difficult. Your body is in homeostasis and wants to stay that way, so your hormones and brain chemistry will be telling you and your body to stay the way it is.  That means your brain will tell you to make poor food choices, and your hormones will tell your body to utilize foods differently.  That's why diet is very important.  Make a spreadsheet, count calories, use fitday, eat strictly paleo, whatever you have to do.

Now, get busy!  You'll be spectacular at the wedding.  Best of luck!

Comment: I agree with you, HIIT methods will drive her to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that picture, you must not only lose fat, but build a fair amount of muscle as well.

```
but a trainer told me women should do lower weight, more reps
```

This is absolute nonsense.

While cardio is certainly beneficial as well, you need to start lifting heavy if you want to look like her.

Comment: I disagree because his goal doesn't even lift. she's just flat. that's it.