# When to change Kettle-bell weight?

Tags: kettlebell

I have got 20kg kettle bell and able to do 30 swings without exhausting.
Should I change the size of kettlebell(32 or 36 kg ?) or increase reps ?

Comment: What's your goal? If it's strength, you should increase weight until you can't do 10 ones with good form anymore, if it's endurance, you'll have to define your own level. Perhaps you'd really like to have the endurance to do 70 swings, then keep going until you can do 70...

Comment: I'm trying to get a body definition, losing my unwanted fat (I'm over weight). Doing more than 30 from 20kg is challenging. But I don't know what would be  best to reach my goal , increasing weight or reps. I do only swings , which is the only exercise I do not feel boring . I moved from 12kg to 20kg few months back.

Comment: Okay, if losing fat is the goal, how you swing will not have a large impact. But if you're looking to become stronger, do 10 reps, rest and repeat for no more than 5 sets. Losing weight is mostly about diet though, and many overweight people find walking a good way to increase their calorie consumption without much of the discomfort that comes with working out while being overweight.

Comment: Thank you . So no need to switch to a higher weight kettlebell ?

Answer (score 2):

> I do only swings , which is the only exercise I do not feel boring

You may want to consider something like the [kettlebell snatch](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBSnatch.html), or the [kettlebell clean and press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBCleanAndJerk.html) (or both), neither of which many people would describe as boring.

Some of my favorite kettlebell workouts consist of:

- [Swing](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTwoArmSwing.html) (two hand)
- Snatch
- Clean and press
- [Turkish getup](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTurkishGetup.html)
- [DB (with a KB) row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/DBBentOverRow.html)

> Should I change the size of kettlebell(32 or 36 kg ?) or increase reps ?

If your goal is fat loss, remember that [strength training has a very big impact to your resting metabolic rate](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117). So perhaps consider using a heavier bell for the big movements that you can leverage (like the double hand swing), and use lighter bells for the snatch, and maybe even a lighter still for the getups.

And to spare you some pain, consider buying some [chalk](https://www.google.com/search?q=gym%20chalk) if you haven't already and use it liberally. It can really save your hands.

Comment: Does it need to do swings until get sweaty to get a result ? I do like 30 reps in the morning but no swetting  . I do not get the science behind gaining muscles and swing , but I definitely have a good feeling after doing . Is it possible to loose 10KG per month just doing swings ?

Answer (score 2):

30 kettlebell swings is not enough exercise to see major improvement. You need a longer workout.

Stay with your current kettlebell, but do more exercises and more sets. You could do 30 swings, then rest a couple minutes, then do another set of 30 swings, and continue until you've done 3 or 5 sets. Some sets of overhead presses would be a good idea, as would Turkish get-ups. Or maybe do swings, then go for a quick jog, then do some push-presses, then do some more swings.

But just one set of 30 swings is not a workout. Do more.

Comment: Thank you Dave . I did set of 25 then 3 sets of 20 . In between like 5min break . My heart rate went high. I can hardly do one push up , I'm 220lbs!

Answer (score 2):

Just for a little reference: Dan John has a programm/blog post kinda thing named 10000 kettlebell swings. In this you perform 500 swings a day 4 times per week (main and only workout) and it contains sets of 50 swings. I tried this with a 24kg kettlebell and can honestly say it is something special. For me personally it puts things in perspectif; I don't think 30 kettlebell swings are a lot.

That said it all depends on your goals, RKC might be something you can look into