# Include Whey Protein in Diet Plan for Weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, diet, nutrition, protein-shakes

I am a 23 year old/ 84 kg/ 178 cms overweight guy. I have started weight loss programme. I run around 6-6.5Kms (Treadmill + Eliptical), do some crunches, belly exercises and then do 2-3 sprints daily and do the same 6 times a week.

I have also reduced my calorie intake.

Breakfast - Corn flakes/Porridge/Fruits/Oatmeal

Lunch- Mix Veg + Bread + Salad + Rice

Dinner - Milk + Sprouts

After workout - 300 ml Mint Lemon with Honey (right after workout)

I was advised by few guys in Gym that i should replace my "After workout + Dinner" diet with Whey Protein shake (300 ml milk + whey + bananas). Want to ask if its right thing to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site's not for weight loss questions or personal diet advice. Maybe try Fitocracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protein needs, and basically everything you eat, should fit into your dietary goals. Those goals generally revolve around your total daily calories and your macro nutrient percentages (aka: macros).

Start with one of the many [calculators available on the Internet](http://iifym.com/iifym-calculator/).

For a couple of weeks, religiously track everything you eat, [using one of the typical calorie tracking systems](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/).

You will probably discover that:

1. You are eating too many refined carbohydrates.
2. You are eating too many carbohydrates.
3. You are not eating enough protein.

Regardless, you would then address your diet and figure out how to meet your dietary goals (whatever the calculator told you). If you need to *supplement* something, typically protein, that's where things like whey comes in.

Make sure that whatever you're doing with your diet is part of a bigger picture, don't just add "super foods", "shakes", and whatever other items without understanding how they fit into your overarching goals.

And no conversation would be complete without mentioning that [strength training done right will have more pronounced fat reduction than aerobic training](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117).

Answer (score 0):

as for weight loss diet = it does not matter WHAT or WHEN you eat but only how much so yes...

whey is fine for weight loss provided you dont consume too much just like candy is okay for weight loss as long as you dont eat too much of it (think about it - if you are on an island stranded where you can only eat 1 cookie a day dont you think you would lose weight fast?)

more protein in your diet will help you lose weight faster since it reduces appetite and you burn more calories digesting protein