# Difficulty losing inches

Tags: weight-loss

I am a lady in her mid-30s.

Before marriage in 2012 I was 5'4", 115 lbs, had a 34" chest, a 26" waist, and 37" hips

In 2014, I had a miscarriage after 12 weeks, and the weight stayed on.

Now, my weight is 145 lbs. I have a 36" chest, a 30" waist, and 40" hips. For the past two months I have done following:

- **Morning**: 16.9 oz bottle of water. 12 minute meditation, 48 [Surya Namaskars](http://www.artofliving.org/us-en/yoga/yoga-poses/sun-salutation), Few inversion exercises. Then 16.9 oz of lemon water
- **Breakfast**: Fruits, Egg in Olive Oil (with black pepper), Once Slice Whole Wheat Bread, Juice, Multivitamin, Fish oil, 24 peeled almonds after they've been soaked.
- **Mid-Morning**: Green Tea
- **Afternoon**: Coffee (tall Pike roast in grande cup, 4 inches for half-and-half, ZERO SUGAR), One slice whole wheat bread with natural peanut butter, 3 walnuts, 3 cashews, 3 pistachios
- **Mid-Afternoon**: Salad (no dressing), Yogurt with little salt and pepper
- **Late-Afternoon**: Peppermint or Chamomile Tea
- **Dinner**: One whole avocado (mashed), with chopped onion, garlic, hot green pepper on slice of whole wheat bread.
- **Before sleep**: One cup of warm milk with turmeric, cinnamon, cacao, NO SUGAR. 12 minutes of meditation.

I am very upset that my stomach is not losing inches. It has been two months. I just visited my doctor, and all blood levels are fine.

How do I resolve this?

#### Update

Forgot to mention I also eat 24 peeled, and previously soaked almonds each morning.

#### Update 2

If it's relevant, obesity runs in our family (along with the related illnesses), and I've been known to have slow metabolism (cannot eat a few cookies without gaining weight), even when I was a little kid.

Comment: Looks like you're under-eating.

Comment: Looks like you're under 1200 calories. Very difficult to lose weight like that because your body will cut back all possible expenditures to conserve energy.

Comment: @Noumenon Under 1200? Really? Are you sure? Because I'm having one egg a day, frying it in olive oil. And don't forget whole avocado. But under 1200??? I'm baffled!!! I was thinking of eliminating the half-and-half and halving the avocado. Under-eating???

Comment: @Noumenon Sometimes I feel I am eating so much that I forget to eat other things, i.e. I'll unintentionally skip Almonds in the morning, or Yougurt in the afternoon.

Comment: @Noumenon By the way, obesity, and related illnesses run in our family. I'm still surprised you are saying I'm undereating ....

Comment: @Rhonda: A fried egg comes up as about 102 calories. Almond oil is 120 calories per 100 grams, and I suspect you're not drinking it down. Honestly, it's really hard to decide without quantities, but it doesn't look like you're eating outrageous amounts of food. Your plan is a little slight on exercise. Yoga and meditation aren't bad things, but they're not exactly likely to kick the metabolic rate up much.

Comment: @Rhonda , check this out http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117

Comment: @SeanDuggan Wow, then I'll lift weights again. I started to lift few months back, and once I began the Surya Namaskars, the weight lifting stopped (I justified to myself that Surya Namaskar is an ancient total-body workout) .

Comment: @Rhonda: Yoga can be a good form of exercise. It's essentially a combination of bodyweight and stetching exercise. The problem is that, as typically practiced, people aren't expending any more effort than they would in a short walk. Regarding diet, do you feel hungry all the time?

Comment: @SeanDuggan No hunger whatsoever. As a matter of fact, I sometimes forget to eat small parts of meals. This morning, I forgot to eat the 24 peeled almonds that I usually do (I'll have them when I return home).

Comment: You can use MyFitnessPal to determine how many calories you're actually eating, but your list is full of 0-calorie items and sub-100-calorie items and it looked like under 1200 to my eyeballing.

Comment: @Noumenon That's a great idea! Websites like those are quiet helpful.